# ionic 3 html5 p tag not expanding for size of text content css not working also

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3, scss-mixins

I am trying to make a html5 p tag display minimum 3 lines of a description inside an ionic 3 ion-item tag as shown below:

```
             <ion-item>
                <ion-avatar item-start>
                  <img src="{{company.logo_url}}" alt="company_logo" *ngIf="company.logo_url">
                </ion-avatar>
                <h2>{{ company.company_name }}</h2>
                <p class="desc-line">{{ company.description_short }}</p>
              </ion-item>
```

The scss I tried to use was:

```
.desc-line {
    display:inline-block;
  }
```

Which didn't work so I also tried:

```
.desc-line {
display: -webkit-box;
overflow : hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical; 
}
```

Now I have no idea of what to try next that will make sense and haven't found any other similar solutions.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this solution but I think it will work,

you can set minimum height, for example:

```
.desc-line {
  min-height: 30px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong.

I have created a [demo as well here on Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ws3mhz)

You just need to add `white-space: normal;` to your `.label` CSS. Moreover, Stackblitz has not allowed me to change `.label` in SCSS file so I have added inline style to `ion-label` element.

```
.item {
  .label {
    white-space: normal;
  }
}
```

Please let me know if this helps.